# Update a table with a CTE and then Delete the record thats no longer valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-delete

After i update the record with the appropriate values in the update statement, i then am trying to delete the record that is no longer valid. 
my Code is as follows, I'm not sure how you would use the values generated in the CTE to delete the values in the table,
any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    WITH CTE AS
(
       SELECT C.CompressorId, C.CompressorSK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY C.Compressorid order by C.EffectiveDate) as RowNumber
         FROM dimCompressor C
         where CompressorId = 8
)

,CTE_MAX AS
(
       SELECT CompressorId, MAX(CTE.RowNumber) AS MaxRow
         FROM CTE
       GROUP BY CompressorId
)

,CTE_SK AS
(
       SELECT DISTINCT c.CompressorId, m1.MaxSK, m2.NextMaxSK
       --, M1.MaxSK, M2.NextMaxSK
         FROM CTE C
         JOIN CTE_MAX M ON C.CompressorId = M.CompressorId




         CROSS APPLY (
                                  SELECT C1.CompressorSK AS MaxSK
                                    FROM CTE C1
                                  WHERE C1.CompressorId = M.CompressorId
                                     AND C1.RowNumber = M.MaxRow
              ) M1
         CROSS APPLY (
                                  SELECT C2.CompressorSK AS NextMaxSK
                                    FROM CTE C2
                                  WHERE C2.CompressorId = M.CompressorId
                                     AND C2.RowNumber = M.MaxRow - 1
              ) M2


)


UPDATE C1
   SET C1.EffectiveDate = C2.EffectiveDate

  FROM CTE_SK S
  JOIN dimCompressor C1 
    ON S.MaxSK = C1.CompressorSK
  JOIN dimCompressor C2
    ON S.NextMaxSK = C2.CompressorSK


-- This is the part i need help with, i need to delete the row associated with the C2.COmpressorSK
delete  FROM CTE_SK S
  JOIN dimCompressor C1 
    ON S.MaxSK = C1.CompressorSK
  JOIN dimCompressor C2
    ON S.NextMaxSK = C2.CompressorSK
```

Comment: You may want to use your CTEs in merge ( [link](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g#delete_clause) ) with a delete clause instead of update.
But i'm not going through your whole query, sorry :)

Comment: You can't - you can only refer to a cte in the statement that directly follows it. There is no way (other then re-writing the entire cte chain again) to do both update and delete where both refer to the same ctes.

Comment: What if i were to run the update statement, and then comment the update statement out, then run the delete statement?

Comment: @Dak What database are you using specifically? That should always be in tags.
Also, your example is cryptic and far from MCVE.

Comment: @piezol  thought you weren't reading the whole query? I'm using SSMS 2017, and its a relational database, idk what your question is asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the CTE twice in that fashion, but instead, why not just use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to capture the information from the UPDATE statement and then use that in the DELETE statement. It will do the same thing without having to repeat the CTE query (which could be quite costly).